# How to create a constant in .sql file

Tags: sql, sonarqube

The .sql file has DML in java project used for testing. Sonar reports duplicate string literals in this file. I tried some available solution creating constant using 'declare' and 'setvar' but did not work. e.g -

Sonar reports location NY as duplicate.

```
INSERT INTO PERSON (ID, NAME, LOCATION, BIRTH_DATE )  VALUES(1,  'Alex', 'NY', '2016-11-16 06:55:40.11');
INSERT INTO PERSON (ID, NAME, LOCATION, BIRTH_DATE )  VALUES(2,  'John', 'NY', '2016-11-16 06:55:40.11');
```

Comment: what exactly is expected output?

Comment: SonarQube tool report 'NY' as repeated string literal  in .sql file. And expect declare a constant and reuse the constant where ever required in .sql file. So, how to create a constant for string literal 'NY' in .sql file so that sonar does not report the same.

Comment: you can set to default while creating the script then there is no need to insert every time

Comment: What need to be set as default?